# Regarding sending a file to Websocket via android application

Tags: android, websocket

I want to upload a mp3 file via Websocket in Android Application.

I was using the external library 
http://autobahn.ws/android/

But the problem is that through this library,I cannot upload a big file.say 5 Mb.
I tried researching on similar types of libraries.But could not found a suitable one.
Has anyone tried to upload file on WebSocket in Android Application.

Thanks

Comment: what is the problem with uploading a 5mb file ? is there any specific error ? what server side technology you are using ?

Comment: I am using AutoWahn Android Library for WebSockets.There is no specific upload method.Have u uploaded a 5 mb file to WebSocket in Android.

Comment: You didn't mentioned the error you are getting while uploading large file through web socket. This is the ideal type question which could not be helped if there are no relevant details attached.

Comment: run() : WebSocketException (de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketException: frame payload too large)

Comment: Edit your question and update the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the mentioned error you are receiving `"WebSocketException: frame payload too large"`, if you go to the [source code of the library](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnAndroid/blob/master/Autobahn/src/de/tavendo/autobahn/WebSocketReader.java#L237) you are using and search for error you will find out the limitation imposed by the library itself.

> // immediately bail out on frame too large
>
> ```
> if (payload_len > mOptions.getMaxFramePayloadSize()) {
>     throw new WebSocketException("frame payload too large");
> }
> ```

You'll find the this limitation in [WebSocketOptions.java](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnAndroid/blob/master/Autobahn/src/de/tavendo/autobahn/WebSocketOptions.java#L46)

> `mMaxFramePayloadSize = 128 * 1024;`